# Why is it possible to access a field without a getter?

Tags: java, generics, hashset

I have the following example:

```
package cage;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import animals.Animal;

public class Cage<T extends Animal> {  //A cage for some types of animals
    private Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

    public void add(T animal)  {
        set.add(animal);
    }

    public void showAnimals()  {
        for (T animal : set) {
            System.out.println(animal.getName());
        }
    }

    public void transferTo(Cage<? super T> cage) {
        cage.set.addAll(this.set);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package exe;

import cage.Cage;
import animals.Animal;
import animals.Ape;
import animals.Lion;
import animals.Rat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test with super........");
        Cage<Animal> animals = new Cage<Animal>();
        Cage<Lion> lions = new Cage<Lion>();
        animals.add(new Rat(true, 4, "Rat", true)); // OK to put a Rat into a Cage<Animal> 
        lions.add(new Lion(true, 4, "King", 9));
        lions.transferTo(animals); // invoke the super generic method -> animals is SUPER of lion.
        animals.showAnimals();
    }
}
```

In the class cage there is an invocation

> cage.set.addAll(this.set);

Why does it work to invoke "cage.set..." with the dot notation althought I have neither a getSet-method nor is "set" static? What's the technical background?

Comment: Hey - that's *my* `transferTo` method from my answer to [this previous question about generics and super bounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826916/useful-example-with-super-and-obscurity-with-extends-in-generics) from @Bevor - nice to see it lives on in your code :)

Comment: Yes, I thought that you missed my question in the other thread so I decided to ask it as a new question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just using field access. Having a `getSet()` method would make no difference, as the Java compiler won't use an accessor method automatically for you.

I suspect what you're missing is that `private` access isn't determined by the *object* whose member you're trying to access - the code in `Cage` has access to the private members of any other `Cage`, including the `set` field.

[Section 6.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6) describes access control, including:

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared `private`, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Comment: Actually it's the same in C++ too.

Comment: @Nicola: Thanks. Odd - I could have sworn this is normally asked by C++ programmers who are surprised that they have access to private members of other objects. Will remove that bit of the answer.

Comment: You were right, that was what confuses me. But I think it's clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
cage.set
```

is simply accessing the field `set` within your object `cage`. The field is declared private but you are still inside the same class `Cage`.

Answer (score 1):

you access it from inside your class. So the private declaration doesn't count.

Try it from your Main class and it will fail, since set is private.

Answer (score 1):

It works because methods from class `Cage` can access private members from the same class `Cage`. It does not matter here that the member in this case is accessed on another instance of the class.