# Use of '? extends ' and '? super ' in Collection generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

Can anybody explain why we use `?` in `Collection` generics.

As for example :

```
 List<? extends Number> numberlist;
 List<? super Integer> numberlist;
```

Comment: You'd prefer another character ?

Comment: You're asking why we use this specific character instead of a different one?

Comment: I already asked something similar a while ago, see...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826916/useful-example-with-super-and-obscurity-with-extends-in-generics


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826916/useful-example-with-super-and-obscurity-with-extends-in-generics

Comment: You mean instead of just working with interfaces?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The wildcards introduce restrictions in how the collection can be used.

For example, with `List<? extends Number>`, I can't add new elements to the list. This is because all I know is that the list is some kind of subtype of `Number`, but I don't know what that actual subtype is (so how could I know what to add?). For example, take the following code:

```
public void doSomethingWith(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(0)); // Won't compile
}
```

This won't compile because both of *these* method calls are legal:

```
doSomethingWith(new ArrayList<Integer>());
doSomethingWith(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

What you *can* do is *read* elements from the list:

```
// This will all compile
public void doSomethingWith(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    for (Number number : numbers) {
        // Do something with number
    }
    // OR
    Number number = numbers.get(0);
    // OR
    Number number = numbers.remove(0);
}
```

Calls to methods like `get` will return some kind of `Number`, we know that for a fact because of the `? extends Number`, so we can treat it like that for reading purposes.

On the other hand, `List<? super Integer>` has exactly the opposite result. I can no longer read from the list, but I can write to it. I know that whatever `?` is, it will definitely be a super-class of `Integer`, so concrete types of the list will definitely accept `Integer` values. For example:

```
public void doSomethingWith(List<? super Integer> integers) {
    integers.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
}
```

That code is completely legal. However, if you want to read from the list, the only way to do this is to use `Object` since anything else requires casting (which requires knowing its concrete type):

```
for (Object obj : integers)
// OR
Object obj = integers.get(0);
// OR
Object obj = integers.remove(0);
```

**What's Really Happening**

Here's what's actually happening. When you specify `? extends Number`, you're making any method that *takes* elements as a parameter unusable. In fact, if you try to auto-complete code in Eclipse using Ctrl+Space on a `List<? extends Number>`, it shows `null` as the parameters' types in the `add` methods and the like. Meanwhile, all the methods that *return* elements are guaranteed to return at least some kind of `Number`, though you won't know exactly which subclass of `Number` it might actually be.

When you specify `? super Integer`, you're making any method that *takes* elements as a parameter guarantee that they'll accept `Integer` values (and sub-classes of `Integer` as well). This allows you to call methods like `add` since you know they'll accept `Integer` types. Meanwhile, all methods that *return* elements are only guaranteed to return *something*, but we don't know what, so all the methods that return elements are only guaranteed to return `Object`.

PECS is an excellent acronym to remember this, it means "**P**roducer **E**xtends, **C**onsumer **S**upers". This means that if you want your list to give you something, it's a producer, and you should use `extends`. If you want your list to accept things from you, it's a consumer, so you use `super`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for more.

**But what if I have a wildcard with no bounds?**

It does both! `<?>` restricts you from calling methods that take the generic type as an argument *and* causes all the methods that return the generic type to return `Object`. This is because we have no idea what the type is whatsoever. For example, all of these assignments into a `List<?>` are legal:

```
List<?> list;
list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Its a wildcard. ? signifies that any class that inherits from number or is a super class of Integer class will work. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you are learning wildcards and diff between **extends** and **super** , simply remember [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs). This rule has all in it with great simplicity to remember.

Answer (score 1):

`?` used to define [wild cards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) while using generics.

The statement you have in example tells that List accepts any object of type `Number`

Answer (score 1):

`?` mean any class so

```
? extends MyClass
```

means any subclass of MyClass or MyClass itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would say:

```
List<? extends Number> numberlist; //Any class that is extended from Number class,  for example Integer, BigInt, ... may come

List<? super Integer> numberlist; //Any class that Integer class is extended from. Here for example Number may come
```

because:

```
Integer extends Number{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<? extends Number>` and `List<Number>` would both allow to add for example Integers, but:
With `List<Number>` you could put in there Integers and anything else that "is" a Number. With `List<? extends Number>` you can put in there only one concrete runtimetype. Be it Integer, then you cannot add another type that's also a Number.