# Why does a type conversion not work in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, casting, covariance

I`m wondering why this conversion is not working:

```
ArrayList<Song> arrayList =new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
```

I may have to add that Song extends MediaItem.
I think this conversion should work because Song has the ability to store all the information form MediaItem. So no information is lost.
Does anyone have an explanation for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-in-java/933600#933600

Comment: What conversion?  You're simply assigning a reference to one object type to a different object type.  Even if it were allowed nothing would be "converted".

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20042341/1081110) to a related question explains this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246137/java-generics-cannot-cast-listsubclass-to-listsuperclass

Comment: You can achieve a safe version of this using contravarience;  an example of this is explored in this question; [Returning a Collection<ChildType> from a method that specifies that it returns Collection<ParentType>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384015/returning-a-collectionchildtype-from-a-method-that-specifies-that-it-returns-c)

Comment: And a more general explanation here; [Use of '? extends ' and '? super ' in Collection generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604477/use-of-extends-and-super-in-collection-generics)

Comment: It should be noted that in this particular case the `ArrayList<MediaItem>` is newly created and hence contains no entries.  As such it is indistinguishable from an empty `ArrayList<Song>` (or an `ArrayList<Potato>` for that matter), and hence allowing the assignment would not "break" anything.  The error being raised is somewhat artificial in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because generic types in Java have no covariance/contravariance. If you could do the assignment like that, one would be able to do this:

```
ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<MediaItem>(); // Legal
ArrayList<Song> songs = mediaItems; // Illegal; let's imagine it's legal for a moment
// Note that songs and mediaItems are the same list
songs.add(new Song());         // This is perfectly fine
Song firstSong = songs.get(0); // That's OK - it's a Song
mediaItems.add(new Video());   // This is perfectly fine, too
// However, the addition above also modifies songs: remember, it's the same list.
// Now let's get the last object from songs
Song lastSong = songs.get(1);  // Wait, that's not a Song, it's a Video!!!
```

Java does not want this to happen. Hence, it prohibits assignments of generic types based on subclasses to generic types based on the corresponding base classes.

Comment: Are you sure your first line is legal? Shouldn't it be MediaItem on both sides

Comment: @RichardTingle Absolutely, you are 100% right! This was a copy-paste error. When you see a blunt error like this, please feel free to edit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone have an explanation for me?

If that assignment were valid, then you could put an instance of another subclass of `Song` (completely unrelated to `MediaItem`) into the list. Hence it's not allowed. In other words, **Java generics are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)**.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because generics in Java not covariant. Meaning, `List<Song>` and `List<MediaType>` are two totally unrelated types, even though `Song` and `MediaType` are related.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ArrayList`s have different **concrete parameterized type** .

Read more about this in [GenericTypes.FAQ101](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ101)

> An instantiation of a generic type where all type arguments are concrete types rather than wildcards.
>   Examples of concrete parameterized types are `List<String>`, `Map<String,Date>`, but not `List<? extends Number>` or `Map<String,?>`.

[Arrays in Java Generics - What are the issues regarding arrays in Java Generics?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm)

> **Generic collections are not covariant**. An instantiation of a parameterized type for a supertype is not considered a supertype of an instantiation of the same parameterized type for a subtype. That is, a `LinkedList<Object>` is not a supertype of `LinkedList<String>` and consequently a `LinkedList<String>` cannot be used where a `LinkedList<Object>` is expected; there is no assignment compatibility between those two instantiations of the same parameterized type, etc.
>
> Here is an example that illustrates the difference:
>
> `LinkedList<Object> objLst = new LinkedList<String>(); // compile-time error`

You can achieve this by erasing parametrized type and casting:

```
ArrayList<Song> arrayList = (ArrayList<Song>) (ArrayList<?>) new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's contradictory. On one hand, an ArrayList of `Song`s is declared, so `Song`s and objects of classes derived from `Song` can be stored there. However, `new ArrayList<MediaItem>()` is creating an ArrayList of the derived type, meaning that other objects derived directly from `Song` *can't* be stored. The difference between the types is irreconcilable.