# List Polymorphism

Tags: java, list, polymorphism

I have these classes:

```
class Parent {
    public Parent() {
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent {
    public ChildA() {
        super();
    }
}

class ChildB extends Parent {
    public ChildB() {
        super();
    }
}

public ListClas(List(Parent) list)   {
    this.list=list;
    }
}
```

And I want to run `ListClas` constructor as  below.

```
List<ChildA> list_childA = new ArrayList<ChildA>();

List<ChildB> list_childB = new ArrayList<ChildB>();

ListClas listClasA = new ListClas(list_childA);

ListClas listClasB = new ListClas(list_childB);
```

But the compiler throws an error. How do I do this correctly using polymorphism?

Comment: Where is it you think you are using polymorphism? Generics and polymorphism aren't the same thing. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940652/why-does-a-type-conversion-not-work-in-java/20940807#20940807

Comment: What is the error? How does `ListClas` look?

Comment: public ListClas(List(Parent) list)   {
    this.list=list;
    }
}

Comment: `public ListClas(List(Parent) list)` is not valid Java. Did you mean `public ListClas(List<Parent> list)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you change to `List<? extends Parent> list` (also change `ListClas.list` field definition) in your **ListClas** then it will compile and work.

Comment: That depends on what type `list` is. If it's just a `List` then it will work, but if it's a `List<Parent>` then it won't work because you'd be assigning an instance of type `List<ChildA>` to a variable of type `List<Parent>`

Comment: `List<Parent>` **can be assigned** to `List<? extends Parent>` as well as `List<ChildA>` and `List<ChildB>`. You can verify that or probably I misunderstood you.

Comment: `List<? extends Parent> list = new ArrayList<ChildA>();` works, but `List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<ChildA>();` doesn't. The OP doesn't show the entire `ListClas` class so it wasn't clear what type `this.list` is. Judging from the type of the `ListClas` constructor parameter `list` in the OP I assumed that the type of `this.list` was also `List<Parent>`

Comment: I assumed that `ListClas.list` field definition must be changed also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that accepts List containing subclasses of a superclass you should use  syntax.

```
public ListClas(List<? extends Parent> list){
    this.list=list;
}
```

It will accept both of them.

```
ListClas listClasA = new ListClas(list_childA);

ListClas listClasB = new ListClas(list_childB);
```

Comment: That depends on what type `this.list` is. If it's just a `List` then it will work, but if it's a `List<Parent>` then it won't work because you'd be assigning an instance of type `List<ChildA>` to a variable of type `List<Parent>`

Answer (score 0):

All of them: `List<Parent>`, `List<ChildA>` and `List<ChildB>` are different concrete parameterized type.

You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940807/516167

Comment: I think the issue here is more `List<ChildA>` being assigned to `List<Parent>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your ListClas to look something like this:

```
class ListClas<T>
{
    private List<T> list;

    public ListClas(List<T> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Then to create them:

```
ListClas<ChildA> listClasA = new ListClas<ChildA>(list_childA);
ListClas<ChildB> listClasB = new ListClas<ChildB>(list_childB);
```

The T is a generic type designation. It allows you to use the same class for multiple runtime types. So you can do the above instead of having to write this:

```
class AListClas
{
    private List<ChildA> list;

    public AListClas(List<ChildA> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

class BListClas
{
    private List<ChildB> list;

    public BListClas(List<ChildB> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

If you don't need quite as much flexibility you could write your ListClas like this:

```
class ListClas
{
    private List<? extends Parent> list;

    public ListClas(List<? extends Parent> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ListClas listClasA = new ListClas(list_childA);
ListClas listClasB = new ListClas(list_childB);
```

Comment: But don't understand T.What is it in this example?

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: I added a 2nd implementation that might work for you.