# Why generic type is not applicable for argument extends super class for both?

Tags: java, generics, extends

Here is the problem that I have been being tried to find the solution.

We have two class definitions. One of two extends other one.

```
    class T{}
    class TT extends T{}
```

The requirement is that there should be a list keeps object extends T

```
    List<? extends T> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But the problem occures when I try to put a TT object ( barely seems it is a subclass of T )
into the list.

```
    list.add(new TT());
```

**Compilation Error Message**

The method add(capture#2-of ? extends Cell) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Cell)

Comment: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zaoK0Z2STlkC&lpg=PP1&dq=Java%20Generics%20and%20Collections&hl=ru&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q=Java%20Generics%20and%20Collections&f=false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();` directly, this can allow all subtypes of T into the list. This is actually little difficult to understand. when you declare it as

```
List<? extends T> list = ...
```

It means that it can allow any unknown subtypes of `T` into the list. But, from that declaration we cannot ensure which is the exact sub-type of `T`. so, we can only add `null` into it

Answer (score 10):

`List<? extends T>` indicates that anything can comes out of it can be cast to T, so the true list could be any of the following:

- `List<T>`
- `List<T2>`
- `List<T3>`
- etc

You can see that even a new `T` cannot safely be added to such a collection because it could be a `List<T2>` which `T` cannot be put into. As such, such List<? extends T> cannot have non null entries added to them.

In this case you may simply want `List<T>`

### So why would you ever use this?!

This contravariance can be useful for method parameters or returns, in which a collection will be read, rather than added to. A use for this could be to create a method that accepts any collection that holds items that are T, or extend T.

```
public static void processList(Collection<? extends Vector3d> list){
    for(Vector3d vector:list){
        //do something
    }
}
```

This method could accept any collection of objects that extends Vector3d, so `ArrayList<MyExtendedVector3d>` would be acceptable.

Equally a method could return such a collection. An example of a use case is described in [Returning a Collection<ChildType> from a method that specifies that it returns Collection<ParentType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384015/returning-a-collectionchildtype-from-a-method-that-specifies-that-it-returns-c).

Comment: Is it possible to instantiate a `List` whose type arguments include a bounded wildcard?  For example, `List<? extends T> list = new ArrayList<? extends T>()`?  I assume no because I receive a compiler error, but what happens when the diamond operator is used like in the OP's example?

Comment: @KevinBowersox With `<>` It compiles, but its an entirely pointless thing to do

Answer (score 7):

> The requirement is that there should be a list keeps object extends T

If you just want a `List` where you can store objects of any class that extend from `T`, then just create a `List` like this:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

The way you've created a list currently, will not allow you to add anything except `null` to it.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun I try to explain that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21453153/2187042) but its because the list cannot be garanteed to accept any object type but null

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Ah! sorry I was away, but I guess you got the answer.

Comment: @codelovesme I can't completely understand your comment. Can you improvise the grammar a bit. Otherwise, I guess you got the point.

Answer (score 3):

There are boundary rules defined for Java Generics when using WildCards

```
  **extends Wildcard Boundary**
```

List means a List of objects that are instances of the class T, or subclasses of T  (e.g. TT).  This means a Read is fine , but insertion would fail as you dont know whether the class is Typed to T

```
**super Wildcard Boundary**
```

When you know that the list is typed to either T, or a superclass of T, it is safe to insert instances of T or subclasses of T (e.g.TT ) into the list.

In your example , you should use "super"

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the other answers posted here, I would simply add that I only use wild cards for method parameters and return types. They're intended for method signatures, not implementations. When I put a wildcard into a variable declaration, I always get into trouble.