# "? extends ParentClass" makes Read only?

Tags: java, generics, null, generic-list, readonly-collection

In the following code Java, I have created a list `nums`. I can assign the another list during the declaration. But new items cannot be added except the `null`. So, does it mean the `nums` is readonly? **Why?** Is it possible to add new items in that list?

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);

List<? extends Number> nums = ints;
nums.add(3.14); //Generates error
nums.addAll(ints);  //Generates error

nums.add(null);     //works
System.out.println(nums.get(0));    //works
```

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452966/why-generic-type-is-not-applicable-for-argument-extends-super-class-for-both). I can't get exact reason.

Comment: I dont know, note that nums.add((Number) new Double(3.14)); results in the error: The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (Number)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: this is a very common misconception; but the conception works in most cases :)

Comment: Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html for more understanding.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to add new items in that list?

Nope... because that code doesn't know what it's "actually" a list of. Imagine if you *could*:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Object> objects = strings; // This is fine
objects.add(new Object()); // Fortunately this *isn't* valid...
System.out.println(strings.get(0).length()); // Or what would this do?
```

Basically, when you use a wildcard like `? extends T` you can only get values *out* via the API... and when you use a wildcard like `? super T`, you can only put the values *in* via the API - because that's what's safe.

Comment: @PradipKharbuja: No, not really. The list itself isn't read-only - you could still add to it via `ints`, or remove from it via `nums`. You just can't *add* to `nums` because of type safety.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not read-only... even though that is typically the intention.

Given a `List<? extends Number>` object, the compiler [converts](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Capture_Conversion) its type to `List<X>` where X is an unknown subtype of Number. Therefore, the object does have an `add(X)` method. We can call the method with an `X` argument... for example, `null`.

And since `get()` returns `X`, we could also call `add()` with a value from `get()` .... Directly invoking `list.add(list.get(i))` won't work, even though it makes sense. We will need a little [helper](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Capture_Helper).

The classic example is `Collections.reverse(List<? extends Object> list)`. This method will modify the `list`, despite the wildcard.

You can also call mutating methods like `clear()`, of course, on any list.

---

That being said, wildcard is indeed mainly for use-site [variance](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Variance), and most often, it conveys the intention from the API designer of whether a type-parameter is intended for *in* or *out*. For example, by declaring `List<? super/extends Foo>`, the API expresses that it intends to *inject T in to*, or,  *get T out of*, the list.

It is a misconception that wildcard makes read/write-only. But this misconception works in most use cases. And the more people having this misconception, the more it becomes a convention...

see my article on wildcard - http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

It's helps when you think of `List<? extends Number> nums` as a `List` of some type of thing that extends `Number`, but you can't be sure what. As such, everything you do with `nums` needs to be able to done to such a thing.

Adding `null` works because `null` can be cast into absolutely anything. Everything else you try to add will fail, because the compiler can't be 100% certain that the thing you're adding extends the thing the list is made of.

Instead of `List<? extends Number> nums` do `List<Number> nums`, because you can still put in anything that extends `Number`.

`?` doesn't mean "anything", it is closer to meaning "some specific but unknown".

Answer (score -1):

Generics is compile time only.

So Compiler will decide what is actual type we are going to use.

```
List<? extends Number>
```

It means we are not sure what actual type of the object.

So Compiler not make sure what is the actual type that list have.