# Generic type conversion for method argument not possible, why?

Tags: java, generics

I am new to generics and have encountered the following problem when I was trying to use them in a small programm of which I will try to give the necessary information.

I will try to give only the necessary but if anything is missing, just let me know and I will provide what is needed.

The first thing is the following interface:

```
1: public interface IPrice<T extends IPrice<T>> {
2:     void setPriceToZero();
3:     T addPrice(T price);
4:     T subtractPrice(T price);
5:     T multiplyPriceByFactor(int factor);
6:     String priceToString();
7: }
```

It is implemented by a class BnSPrice; here the probably necessary part of it:

```
1: public class BnSPrice implements IPrice<BnSPrice> {
2:     public BnSPrice subtractPrice(BnSPrice price) {...}
2: }
```

Now the part which won't compile and which i don't really understand:

```
1: public static void main(String[] args){
2:     [...]
3:     IPrice<? extends BnSPrice> test = new BnSPrice(5);
4:     test.subtractPrice(new BnSPrice(5));
5:     [...]
6: }
```

What i get is

> "Error:(27, 28) java: incompatible types: main.bnsCalculatorModel.BnSPrice >cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends >main.bnsCalculatorModel.BnSPrice"

in the line where i call the subtract-method.

Why does this happen and how can I correct this so that I can still program to the interface?

(My goal is that it should be easy to extend my program with other "kinds of prices" in the future.)

Comment: Add line numbers please! Is the error in the line `IPrice<? extends BnSPrice> test = new BnSPrice(5);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why generic type is not applicable for argument extends super class for both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452966/why-generic-type-is-not-applicable-for-argument-extends-super-class-for-both)

Comment: Line numbers added; error was in codeblock 3 line 4. Sweeper did a good job at explaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's see how to make this work:

```
IPrice<BnSPrice> test = new BnSPrice(5);
test.subtractPrice(new BnSPrice(5));
```

Okay, so removing the wildcard `? extends ...` works. Why?

You need to understand the concept of generic wildcards. `<? extends BnPrice>` means that this can be any type that is a subclass of `BnPrice`. At the moment, you don't have any, but let's create one in order to demonstrate my point.

```
class MyPrice extends BnPrice {}
```

Note that you can't assign a `BnPrice` object to a variable of type `MyPrice`.

Great! Now we have our `test` object. Let's see how the `subtractPrice` is defined in the type `IPrice<? extends BnPrice>`:

```
T subtractPrice(T price);
```

Since you wrote `<? extends BnPrice>` `T` can be any subclass of `BnPrice` i.e. it can be `BnPrice` or `MyPrice`. If `T` is `BnPrice`, then this would compile:

```
test.subtractPrice(new BnSPrice(5));
```

You're passing a `BnPrice` into a method that expects a `BnPrice`. All good. *But*, `T` does not necessarily have to be `BnPrice`. It can be `MyPrice` as well! What if it were `MyPrice`? Then the above line would not compile because you can't pass a `BnPrice` to a `MyPrice` parameter.

Since the parameter can be any type that extends `BnPrice`, you can't pass a `BnPrice` to it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to some degree for me; at least the point you made about the compiler not knowing if the type in your example was a MyPrice or a BnSPrice; it is a little bit hard to grasp why the contract we made via the interface is not sufficient but i have a vague idea that it would be only sufficient in my special case but not generally; it could be that i try to invoke methods which exist in one subtype but not in the other. Am i thinking in the right direction? Oh, one follow up question: is your first codeblock the most general version i can get?

Comment: @Wolfone I think you are thinking in the right direction, and yes, as far as I'm concerned, that is practically the most general version you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Because the type of test is `IPrice<? extends BnSPrice>`, so the expected type of the argument of subtract is `? extends BnSPrice`, not BnSPrice.

This will compile:

```
BnSPrice test = new BnSPrice(5);
test.subtractPrice(new BnSPrice(5));
```