# Generics in Java - Why I am not allowed to do Comparable<? extends T> instead of Comparable<? super T>?

Tags: java, generics

I have rewritten this `ArrayIndexComparator` class based on this answer of Jon Skeet so that it can support generic types: [Get the indices of an array after sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting#answer-4859279)

```
public class ArrayIndexComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private final T[] array;

    public ArrayIndexComparator(T[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public Integer[] createIndexArray() {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            indexes[i] = i; // Autoboxing
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2) {
        // Autounbox from Integer to int to use as array indexes
        return array[index2].compareTo(array[index1]);
    }
}
```

And I can use this class as long as the `T` type or a supertype of `T` implements the `Comparable` interface (`Comparable<? super T>`).

If I write `Comparable<? extends T>` instead of `Comparable<? super T>`, the compiler gives me an error:

```
@Override
public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2) {
    // Autounbox from Integer to int to use as array indexes
    return array[index2].compareTo(array[index1]); // ERROR -> compareTo (capture<? extends T>) in Comparable cannot be applied to (T)
}
```

What does this `compareTo (capture<? extends T>) in Comparable cannot be applied to (T)` error mean?

I can assume that it does not make sense to define a class `AClass` which implements `Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass>`, but yet it is possible:

```
class AClass implements Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass> {


    @Override
    public int compareTo(AChildClassOfAClass o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class AChildClassOfAClass extends AClass {
}
```

In this strange scenario, I assume to be able to use `ArrayIndexComparator` if I have defined it as `ArrayIndexComparator<T extends Comparable<? extends T>>`, because in this case `T` is `AClass` which implements `Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass>` which turns out to be a subclass of `AClass` (therefore `Comparable<? extends T>` → `Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass extends AClass>`).

Of course, it makes more sense to use `Comparable<? super T>`, but I guess I should be able to do it anyway if I want to.

Why doesn't Java allow me to do this?

Thank you very much for your attention.

**EDIT:** after reading answer to the question [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java), here is what I understood and I hope I understood it correctly:

`array[index1]` is of type T but `compareTo` would expect a type `<? extends T>`, i.e. an unknown specific type of `T` (or `T` itself, but the compiler can't assure that).

Therefore the compiler can't safely cast `T` to the specific unknown type, whereas it could do it if we use `<? super T>` because in this case `compareTo` would expect an unknown supertype of `T` as a parameter, and as we are passing `T`, the compiler can safely cast the type `T` to its supertype as a type `T` is also a `supertype of T` (like when we say that an `Integer` is also a `Number`, but a `Number` is not necessarily an `Integer`).

In this `Comparable<? extends T>` case we are trying to consume `array[index1]` by passing it to the `compareTo` method, but the compiler can't safely cast the type `T` to the specific type required by `compareTo(<? extends T>)`, which is unknown.

That's why I get the error.

Are this thoughts right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: The only type-safe assumption the compiler can make is that an instance of T can be treated as an instance of a supertype of T (when passed to `compareTo()`). It can not, on the other hand, safely cast any possible instance of T to any possible subtype of T (which is what it would have to do with `Comparable<? extends  T>` was used). `compareTo` is a consumer function here. Consumers super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error generally means you're trying to encode a constraint that doesn't make sense.  In your case, we already know there's something that doesn't make sense:

> in this case `T` is `AClass` which implements `Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass>`

**This** is the real issue.   Your classes allow you to do `base.compareTo(child)`, but not `child.compareTo(base)`.  You've tweaked the generic parameters to handle this, but you've merely pushed the problem elsewhere (and luckily the compiler is clever enough to spot it!).

#### What the error is actually saying

`compareTo` takes a `? extends T`.  i.e. some **specific yet unknown** type that extends `T`.  The compiler is complaining because we're attempting to pass in a `T` - that won't be the same as (nor assignable to) the unknown type, in general.  The only thing we can pass into such a method is `null`.

#### Further reading

- [*Why generic type is not applicable for argument extends super class for both?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452966/why-generic-type-is-not-applicable-for-argument-extends-super-class-for-both) (a simpler variant of the same problem)
- [*What is PECS?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) (a structured way to think about `super` vs. `extends` wildcards)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am sorry, but still I don't get it. What if still do not want to do `child.compareTo(base)`, I should be able to do it, shouldn't I?

Comment: @tonix - But your code is doing `a.compareTo(b)`, where all that's known is that `a` and `b` are both of type `T`.  `T` could be either base or child in your scenario.

Comment: Maybe I start to understand. In this line `return array[index2].compareTo(array[index1]);` both array[index2] and `array[index1]` are of type `T`. But my doubt now is, desn't  `? extends T` comprehend `T + any subtype of T`?

Comment: @tonix - No, that would only be the case if the method took a `T`.  But it takes `? extends T`, i.e. the compiler can't know what *specific* type is valid.  So the only thing you can pass in here is `null`.

Comment: I read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java and will read your further readings as soon as I have time. Please, could you tell me if what I wrote in my EDIT is correct? Thank you very much

Comment: @tonix - Yes, the stuff in your EDIT looks exactly correct to me :)

Answer (score -1):

To manage a `?` generic type argument, the compiler uses "captures"; in your case, the `capture-of-? super T`.

The generic term `? super T` means "any superclass of T"; so note it can be `Object`; so you might have a `Comparable<Object>` when that method is called. However, this is not valid:

```
Comparable<AChildClassOfAClass> yourComparable == new YourClass();
yourComparable.compareTo(new Object());
```

which is what your code might get into with that definition.

Comment: But the question is about why `? extends T` doesn't work - `? super T` compiles.