# how to Validate soap request according to WSDL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, soap

i am trying to create an validation according to wsdl using following code:

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {

    PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("test.xsd"));
    interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);

}
```

but i am getting following error :

```
  The method add(EndpointInterceptor) in the type List<EndpointInterceptor> is not applicable for the arguments (PayloadValidatingInterceptor)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452966/why-generic-type-is-not-applicable-for-argument-extends-super-class-for-both

Comment: no , i have searched for how to switch on validation according to wsdl(https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-validate-soap-request-response-xsd-schema/), i found above code but when i try to use it i get above error, so i need help in how to implement the wsdl validation

Comment: so, perhaps this question should be a comment on that website?

Comment: i tried reaching out but there is no response

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the page; 'leave a reply'. There are no replies, so it seems you haven't done this already.