# Why is it not possible to call List<Number> not with List<Integer> even if Integer extends Number?

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering why is it not possible to call `List<Number>` not with `List<Integer`> even Integer is an extended class of the abstract class Number ? There is a logical error as I could call a Method with the parameter Number also with Integer.

```
public class Que
{

public void enterNumbers(List<Number> nummern)
{
    for (Number number : nummern)
    {
        System.out.println(number + "\n");
    }
}

public void enterNum(Number num)
{
    System.out.println("This is a number " + num);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Que que = new Que();

    Integer myInteger = new Integer(7);
    // possible (of course!)
    que.enterNum(myInteger);

    List<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    num.add(4);
    num.add(45);
    Integer inte = new Integer(333);

    num.add(inte);
    // not possible ! 
    que.enterNumbers(num);
}
}
```

To solve it I could work with `List<?>` or `List<? extends Number>`... so I don't need the solution I want to know the exact reason.

The only solution I could think of List is bind with Number as a new Type of Data Structure.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: Think about it: `List<Number>` you can add a `Double`. `List<Integer>` you cannot add a `Double`.

Comment: Because generics are not covariant like arrays. See [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17384083/1348195) on more details.

Comment: Take a look at: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: I don't get why people write proper answers as comments which cannot be ticked as correct?!

Comment: You can find a good tutorial about it here . http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/27/generics-polymorphism-with-generics/

Comment: If you want to call the method with a `List<Integer>`, you could use a wildcard in the paramterized type instead: `List<? extends Number> nummern`, meaning a `List` of `Number` or some subtype of `Number`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you could e.g. add an instance of a different subclass of `Number` to `List<Number>`, e.g., an object of type `Double`, but obviously you shouldn't be allowed to add them to `List<Integer>`:

```
public void myMethod(List<Number> list) {
    list.add(new Double(5.5));
}
```

If you were allowed to call `myMethod` with an instance of `List<Integer>` this would result in a type clash when `add` is called.

Answer (score 8):

Generics are not co-varient like arrays. This is not allowed because of type erasure.

Consider classes `Vehicle`, `Bike` and `Car`.

If you make

```
public void addVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicles){
    vehicles.add(new Car());
}
```

- This is possible, because a `Car` is of type `Vehicle`, you can add a
  `Car` into `Vehicle` because it passes IS-A test.
- But what if it was allowed to pass a `List<Bike>` to `addVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicles)` ?

**you would have added a `Car` to bike list. which is plain wrong. So generics doesn't allow this.**

Read about [Polymorphism with generics](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/27/generics-polymorphism-with-generics/)