# Why a Map with superclass values can't accept subclass objects?

Tags: java

I have two classes: superclass Cluster and subclass XCluster. XCluster extends Cluster.

I have this method signature:

```
public Map<Integer, XCluster> getClusters() {
...
}
```

I have this variable:

```
Map<Integer, Cluster> clusters = getClusters();
```

I can't compile this. Eclipse says that the method getCluster() doesn't return this kind of type. That I need to change the type from XCluster to Cluster.

What's wrong?

Comment: Similar question a few minutes ago. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513990/why-is-it-not-possible-to-call-listnumber-not-with-listinteger-even-intege

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because: [generics in Java are not polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Your main options (there are others):

- change the second code to

  ```
  Map<Integer, ? extends  Cluster> clusters = getClusters();
  ```
- change the method signature to:

  ```
  public Map<Integer, Cluster> getClusters() {}
  ```

Which to use depends on your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what would happen if you tried to insert a `Cluster` into `clusters`.  Since the result of `getClusters()` can only hold `XCluster`s, there should be an error.  You are correct, however, that if any value you retrieve from the map would be a `Cluster`, so you could do, for instance,

```
Cluster cluster = getClusters().get( 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

because a `Map<Integer, XCluster>` is not a `Map<Integer, Cluster>`. Generics does not work this way with polymorphism.  You can read about [Polymorphism with generics](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/27/generics-polymorphism-with-generics/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513990/why-is-it-not-possible-to-call-listnumber-not-with-listinteger-even-intege/18514207#18514207)

Answer (score 1):

Java generics won't allow you to do that. An object of type `Map<Integer, XCluster>` is not the same as an object of type `Map<Integer, Cluster>`, even if `XCluster` extends or implements `Cluster`, as explained here: [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot decide that values column contains a superclass. It will not check at that granular level.