# Generics <? super> wildcard

Tags: java, generics, collections

I was wondering why the following bit of code does not work:

```
Collection <? super String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
col.add(new Object());// does not compile
col.add("yo!");// compiles indeed;
```

If the type is `<? super String>` it can contain anything which is super of `String` (String included) not?

Comment: `<? super String>` can only add String. `Object` can be not String.. Try to do: `Object myObj = new String();` and it should work.

Comment: No, anything that **extends** String. It means *? whose super is String*.

Comment: @m0skit0 that's where I got confused. Thanks.

Comment: @m0skit0 Ops.. Why If I then try to do `<? super String> col = new ArrayList<Object>();` it compiles! But Objects don't extend String! These genereics..

Comment: Sorry, my bad, see Marko's answer.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604477/use-of-extends-and-super-in-collection-generics/12605337#12605337

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Collection<? super String>`, counter to your intuition, *does not mean* "a collection which contains objects of type `String` or its supertype". It means "`col` will be a collection holding some definite type, which itself is `String` or its supertype" (such as `Object`, `Serializable`, or `CharSequence`).

The best way to think about `Collection<? super String>` is that it is not a type, like you are used to in Java, but a *pattern* against which specific types are matched.

Now, the only thing you can safely add to any collection which matches the above pattern is a `String` or its subclass (if there were any). Quite the opposite of what you would have expected, isn't it? That's Generics for you.

Comment: Heh, nice. To complete your example, a `String` could be placed into a `Collection<? super CharSequence>`...

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation Marko, it's not the first time your answer helps me

Answer (score 3):

With a `Collection <? super String>`, we don't know what kind of objects it contains exactly, but we know that it must be a collection of either `String` or some superclass of `String`, i.e. it is safe to *put* a `String` into it but not necessarily an `Object`.  Conversely for methods that *take* things out of the collection (e.g. when iterating) we can't be sure we'll get strings back.

On the other hand with `Collection<? extends Foo>` we know it's a collection of something that is either `Foo` or some subclass of `Foo`, so we can safely *take* something from the collection and know it will be assignable to `Foo`, but we can't *put* anything in because we have no way of knowing what types would be safe.

Comment: Great explanation, I understand better now~