# unable to understand wildcard generics in this example in Java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

while reading through this [article](http://jdevelopment.nl/java-best-practices-5-code-to-interface-access-by-name-and-instance-data/) I got stuck here. I am pasting this from the link. I do not understand the reasoning given for why `List<Number>` or `List<? extends Number>` cannot be used here.

```
public void doStuff( List<Integer> list ) {     
    list.add(1);
    // do stuff
    list.get(0);    
}

We can generalize this one step further by generalizing the generic parameter:

public void doStuff( List<? super Integer> list ) {     
    list.add(1);
    // do stuff
    list.get(0);    
}
```

> Some readers might ask why the more intuitively List<Number> can’t be used here. Indeed, we 
>           could try to define the method as taking a List<Number> or a List<? extends Number>, but the first 
>          definition would exclude the possibility for passing in an actual ArrayList<Integer>, while the 
>           second definition would disallow the add() method (as someone may otherwise be passing an 
>           ArrayList<Float> in, and would find an Integer to be between the Floats after the call to doStuff).

Comment: Read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605337/646634)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal Java, yes, an `Integer` is a `Number`.  But in generics, `List<Integer>` is not a `List<Number>`.

To see why, attempt to assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>` and see what happens:

```
List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // not allowed
// This would have been allowed, even though the argument is
// boxed to a `Double`, not a `Integer`.
numberList.add(8.6);
```

But what about `<? extends Number>`?  Wouldn't that cover a `List<Integer>`?  Yes, but the references loses information about the exact type of `Number`.  What if that was the case?

```
List<? extends Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // allowed
numberList.add(8.6);  // disallowed
```

The reason is that the `List<? extends Number>` could be of anything that extends `Number`, such as `List<BigDecimal>`.  So it must disallow calling the `add` method (or any method in that class with the generic type parameter as a parameter to that method) (except for `null`) to maintain type safety.

Comment: does it mean if `employee extends person {}`, I cannot have List<person> p = new ArrayList<employee>`

Comment: That is correct.  Such a list would let you add a `Contractor` (that also extends `Person`), even though the list is actually a `List<Employee>`.  So, that is disallowed.

Comment: assuming no body extends person except employee, is that still illegal

Comment: It would still be illegal, because Java can't make any assumptions that no other class extends another class.  Besides, you _could_ make a `Contractor` class in the future, and the type safety must hold even then.

Comment: by saying `? super Integer`, do we mean any object whose superclass is integer correct..and `? extends Number`, do we mean any object that extends Number class..

Comment: Close.  `? super Integer` means that the generic type parameter is `Integer` or a superclass thereof -- it could be `Integer`, `Number`, or `Object`.  `? extends Number` could be any class that extends `Number` (or `Number` itself).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39952/discussion-between-user1988876-and-rgettman)

Answer (score 1):

Java is perhaps a bit confusing because there is a bit of a double standard at work.

First you must consider that both arrays and collections are reference types, i.e. their instances are objects whose data is allocated to heap memory and indicated by a reference pointer.

Both arrays and collections therefore have **two types** at work: the type of object itself as well as the types of each of the components in the array or collection.  To make this concrete, here is an example:

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
```

The type of the object that is created is `String[]` and the types of all the components is `String`.

Arrays are **covariant** which allows the JVM to cast both the object type and the component type together.  This is why assignments like this are valid:

```
Object[] objects = strings;
```

For arrays, because `Object` is a supertype of `String`, then `Object[]` is also a supertype of `String[]`.  Arrays are covariant.

This does NOT apply to reference types that are not arrays, eg. Collections.  Collections are invariant.  Therefore, even though a `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, collections are invariant and so `List<Integer>` is NOT a subtype of `List<Number>`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, accepting a `List<Number>` *only* allows a `List` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, ...) of **`Number`** elements, not a `List` of any other type (including `Integer`). The list has to be specifically typed in the calling function as `List<Number>` (or `ArrayList<Number>`, or `LinkedList<Number>`, or ...). In other words, the type of list is flexible but the generic argument is not.

In the second case, use the "is a" wording and it makes sense. An `Integer` "is a" `Number`, but the reverse is not always true. Since the code in the example is assuming all values in use within the function are integers, it must put a limit on the generic that prevents anything less specific than `Integer` from being passed in.

Answer (score -1):

We need to examinate two things:

1. What does the wildcard mean in the signature `void doStuff(Foo<? super Bar> foo)`
2. What does the wildcard mean inside the method body

Java has **only one very simple rule** to decide the subtype relation between `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>`: **none is a subtype of the other**. We say that generic types are invariant, and even if there's a rationale because the Java designers made it this way, from your point of view it's an arbitrary decision.

It's the angle brackets that confuse us, poor developers: we have no problem in accepting that `FooBar` and `FooQoo` are not related in any way; but for some reason we need to believe that `Foo<Qoo>` and `Foo<Bar>` are. No, that's not the case.

> No matter how A and B relate to each other, `X<A>` and `X<B>` are not
>   related.
>
> No matter how A and B relate to each other, `X<A>` and `X<B>`
>   are not related.
>
> No matter how A and B relate to each other, `X<A>`
>   and `X<B>` are not related.

Once you are convinced of the above, please observe this snippet:

```
List<Double> doubles = ...;
List<Integer> integers = ...;

Number firstDouble = doubles.get(0);
Number firstInteger = integers.get(0);
```

Calling `get(0)` on both lists gives us a Number-compatible object. We may want to put the call to `get()` in a method like `getFirstOfList(list)` but we just learned that such a method can't exist, because it would accept two totally unrelated types.

This is where **wildcards** come into play! We observe that calling `get()` on a `List<Number>`, a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Double>` (and so on) return a *Number-compatible* object (ie `Number` or a subtype of it), so there must be a way to express this at the language level. The Java designers gave us the wildcard, which works like this: when you declare

```
public void doStuff(List<? extends Number> arg);
```

it has the same effect as declaring the following **infinite** list:

```
public void doStuff(List<Number> arg);
public void doStuff(List<Integer> arg);
public void doStuff(List<Double> arg);
public void doStuff(List<Float> arg);
public void doStuff(List<BigDecimal> arg);
...
```

Without the device of the wildcard you'd have to write one method for each supported list type (which btw is illegal in Java, but that's another story).

The wildcard I used in my example has an *upper* bound, identified by the `extends` keyword. The snippet you pasted, instead, adopts a *lower* bounded wildcard in the method signature (`super`). Actually it may contain some errors because for example:

1. you can't pass a `List<Integer>` to `doStuff()`
2. you can only get an `Object` from `list.get(index)`

so I will just tell you that the signature

```
void doStuff(List<? super Number> arg);
```

stands for the **finite** list:

```
void doStuff(List<Number> arg);
void doStuff(List<Object> arg);
```

and you can put any `Number` you like in a `List<? super Number>` but you'll only `get()` `Object`'s from it.