# Why don't HashMap.containsKey method constraint parameter types?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have no idea why I can pass any type of value to the [HashMap.containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method. I assume this method is an instance method *(correct me if I am wrong)* of [HashMap Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which should be constrained by generic typing. If **JAVA** doesn't want to constrain it , why does the [HashMap.put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method need to match the type it is parameterized with ...

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // invalid
    // map1.put(1, "a");
```

I can't put `int` value key to my `HashMap` `map` having the key type of `String`. What is different between both the [containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) and [put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)  methods ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("1", "a");
    map1.put("2", "b");
    map1.put("3", "c");
    if (map1.containsKey(1)) {
        System.out.println("contain");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("not contain");
    }
}
```

In the above code,`not contain` was output, and the compiler didn't object. If it did, It would prevent this mistake from happening! Am I right? If not, please guide me to the truth.
Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note that in the [Javadoc for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) 
`Map.containsKey()` takes an `Object` as its argument. The class was added in Java 1.2 prior to generics, and when generics were added in 1.5 the method signature wasn't changed.

This means when you do:

```
if (map1.containsKey(1)) {
```

`1` gets autoboxed to an `Integer` object.  Then during the key lookup, the `hashcode()` method is called for that `Integer` object to see if it exists in the `Map`. And ... it doesn't.

You would need to convert that `int` to a `String` for it to work correctly given your `Map<String,String>`:

```
if (map1.containsKey(String.valueOf(1)) {
```

Comment: This isn't true. If this were the case, why would they change `get(Object)` to `get(K)` in the `Map` interface?

Comment: @Brian Re-reading what I wrote originally re: generics you're correct. I think I really meant to type classes rather than interfaces but even that's prob not entirely accurate. But since that wasn't really the important part of the answer in the first place ... edited.

Answer (score 2):

The answer revolves around PECS, a concept I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604477/use-of-extends-and-super-in-collection-generics/12605337#12605337).

The short story is that with `Map<?, ?>`, I cannot call `Map.containsKey(K)` with the generic parameter, even though it technically isn't a consumer method. By making it `Map.containsKey(Object)`, I can call `containsKey` no matter what the type is, which is useful in wildcard-bound maps.

Answer (score -1):

The `containsKey` method has the following signature :

`public boolean containsKey(Object key)`.

So when you pass it an `int` , it uses the argument's `equals` method to determine equality.
As your keys are `Strings` , `"1".equals(1)` returns false.

Comment: can you describe me brief codes of `containsKey` method ? Please..

Comment: @brian roach 's answer has a better explanation than mine on this.