# Why can't I assign an instance with another type to a parameterized variable?

Tags: java, generics

Why can't I do this:

```
LinkedList<Fruit> myFruits = new LinkedList<Apple>();
```

Error message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList<Apple> to LinkedList<Fruit>
```

Where is the difference to the following?

```
Fruit fruit = new Apple();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is \`List<Dog>\` a subclass of \`List<Animal>\`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider what you can do with a `LinkedList<Fruit>` - and think about what you'd want this code to do:

```
LinkedList<Apple> apples = new LinkedList<Apple>();
LinkedList<Fruit> fruits = apples;
fruits.add(new Banana());

Apple apple = apples.getFirst(); // Safe at compile time, but it's a Banana!
```

The conversion is the *only* place it makes sense for this to fail at compile-time. Now what you *can* write is:

```
LinkedList<? extends Fruit> myFruits = new LinkedList<Apple>();
```

... and then the compiler won't let you *add* anything to the list, as it doesn't know what the real element type is. Likewise you coudl write:

```
LinkedList<? super Apple> apples = new LinkedList<Fruit>();
```

Now you can *add* apples to the list, but you can't get apples *out* of the list, as again you don't know what the type would be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just found http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828257/562769 which also helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Polymorphism** simply doesn't apply to `generic types`.

`LinkedList<Fruit>` is not same as `LinkedList<Apple>` even though **Fruit** is a super class of **Apple.**

Refer to this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770) for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because then you could add an `Orange` to `myFruits` and that shouldn't work as the actual list is a list of `Apple`

For example (If you could make this);

```
List<Apple> myApples = new LinkedList<Apple>();
List<Fruit> myFruits = new LinkedList<Apple>();
myFruits.add(new Orange());
```

now myApples got an `Orange` in it

Answer (score 0):

A simple assignement is allowed because the reference is copied and the original is left untouched.

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
Fruit fruit = apple;
fruit = new Banana(); // apple is not touched and is still an Apple
```

whereas (AtomicReference to be a simple collection)

```
AtomicReference<Apple> apple = new AtomicReference<>(new Apple());
AtomicReference<Fruit> fruit = (AtomicReference) apple; // warning but compiles.
fruit.set(new Banana()); // this alters apple as well, making it invalid!
Apple apple2 = apple.get(); // throws ClassCastException.
```