# Java generics - is it possible to restrict T to be Serializable?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to make something like this? I know that `implements` cannot be in the <>, but I want to restrict the T to be Serializable somehow.

```
public class Clazz<T implements Serializable> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried `extends` but I had an error so I thought it was wrong. Then I found there was another issue and `extends` really works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics - why is “extends T” allowed but not “implements T”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public class Clazz<T extends Serializable> {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use *extends* instead of *implements*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just use `extends` instead of `implements`.