# In Java does 'extends' also means 'implements' in this case?

Tags: java, generics

I want a method that processes a list of any type that implements a particular interface.

```
public interface Encryptable {
    public void encrypt() throws Exception ;
}

class DomainClass implements Encryptable {

    String name ;

    public void encrypt() throws Exception {
        try {
            name = CryptoUtils.encrypt(name);
        } 
    }
}
```

This  utility method can encrypt a List of any domain class that implements Encryptable.

```
public static void encryptList ( Collection<? extends Encryptable> listToEncrypt    ) {
    for ( Encryptable objToEncrypt: listToEncrypt ) {
        try {
            objToEncrypt.encrypt() ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a test app and this appears to work.  What concerns me is the Java keyword 'extends'.  My classes do not extend Encryptable they implement it.  Does what I've written really work or am I the victim of some sort of side effect of doing things wrong but getting the right answer.

Comment: You're doing the things right. This is covered in [Lesson: Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) from Oracle Java tutorial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971888/implements-vs-extends-in-generics-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're doing the right thing. You are using an *upper-bounded wildcard*, according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html):

> To declare an upper-bounded wildcard, use the wildcard character ('?'), followed 
>   by the extends keyword, followed by its *upper bound*. Note that, in this context,
>   extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or
>   "implements" (as in interfaces).

But you should be cautious when using [multiple bounds with type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). In multiple bounds type parameter you have to specify the class name first and then interfaces.

Comment: Note that multiple bounds aren't possible with wildcards, just type parameters.

Comment: @Paul Bellora Thank you very much for correcting me.I have updated answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it right. This is a little ambiguous, but yes you're right. But keep in mind that you can always use an interface instead of a class and then `extends` does makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

As always, JLS has answer to this.

See [Section 8.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) for grammer of generics Type Parameters:

```
TypeParameters:
    < TypeParameterList >

TypeParameterList:
    TypeParameterList , TypeParameter
    TypeParameter
```

And [Section 4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) for grammer of `TypeParameter`:

```
TypeParameter:
    TypeVariable TypeBoundopt

TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType AdditionalBoundListopt

AdditionalBoundList:
    AdditionalBound AdditionalBoundList
    AdditionalBound

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

You can see that it uses `extends` keyword for `ClassOrInterfaceType`, in `TypeBound`. Also see [Section 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) for grammer of Type Arguments and Wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Here is a somewhat old but still valid explanation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html), written back when generics were first introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You write it right. In Generics is only the keyword "extended" allowed, either you extend from a class or you implement an interface.