# How to create instance of a class that extends interface?

Tags: java, class, reflection, interface, instance

I have a method like this:

```
public IMyInterface factoryMethod(Class<? extends IMyInterface> concreteClass){
    IMyInterface o = concreteClass.newInstance();
    //...some stuff
    return o;
}
```

If method invoked I get exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packages/IMyInterface`

Seems that it tries to find class `IMyInterface` and then find its constructor. Of course it fails.

How to fix this method?

Comment: Are you certain IMyInterface is on your classpath? Usually a NoClassDefFoundError is a runtime error raised due to classpath issues.

Comment: Can you create instance of your class without reflection? `NoClassDefFoundError` usually happens when class that your code depends on was presented at class path while compiling, but is not in classpath while executing code.

Comment: Can you show snippets of the rest of your code. For example, IMyInterface?

Comment: @Jason But in generics bounds you use `extends` for interfaces as well as classes.

Comment: Class cannot extend interface!! Here you can look at very nice explanations and examples for interfaces --> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

Comment: @i-bob Read rgettman's comment (the one above your comment). Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/976441/1393766).

Comment: That was issue with classpath. I work on ear app. And I had issue with links between jar packages.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and its working fine. But i was also able to reproduce your issue.

Assuming, you are calling

```
factoryMethod(MyClass.class);
```

Then, if the class "MyClass" is inside its **OWN Classfile** its working fine with just providing

```
concreteClass.newInstance();
```

When having the implementation of the class as a **inner Class Type**, the *Class not found exception* is thrown.

The reason is, that a **inner class** is actually a type of a nested class, and therefore creating a instance is only possible, when working with the **enclosing** Class, also.

In the example given bellow, the `newInstance()` method has been used along with an inner class.

```
  public class Test {

    public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    }

    public interface MyInterface {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyInterface ret = method(MyClass.class);

        if (ret instanceof MyClass){
            System.out.println("Is MyClass");
        }
    }

    public static MyInterface method(Class<? extends MyInterface> actualClass){
        try {
            Class<?> enclosingClass = Class.forName(actualClass.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName());
            Object enclosingInstance = enclosingClass.newInstance();

            Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName(actualClass.getName());
            Constructor<?> constructor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(enclosingClass);

            Object innerInstance = constructor.newInstance(enclosingInstance);
            return (MyInterface) innerInstance;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for investigation, but MyClass is not the inner class