# Java - Passing ArrayList of object to function that uses ArrayList of interface that object implements

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters, interface

I have a few ArrayList of objects that implement an interface and I want to pass them to a function that deals with the interface.

The problem is I can't pass an ArrayList of the object to a function that accepts an ArrayList of the interface

Edit: Functions that use ArrayList of the object will not be able to accept an ArrayList of the interface. Can this be done without creating two lists?

Edit: Question marked as duplicate. I understand the issue however the previous question doesn't state if there is a solution for passing a list of object to a list of interfaces.

A simplified version of my problem below

```
    //Interface
public interface SomethingInterface{
    abstract void doesntmatter();
}
//Object
public class SomethingObject implements SomethingInterface{
    public void doesntmatter(){}
}
//Second Object
public class SomethingObject2 implements SomethingInterface{
    public void doesntmatter(){}
}
//Function that wants to be able to accept all objects that implement the interface
public void PassToInterface(ArrayList<SomethingInterface> list){
    for(SomethingInterface i : list){
        i.doesntmatter();
    }
}
//Function that uses list of one of the objects
public void PassToObject(ArrayList<SomethingObject> list){
    //Do something
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<SomethingObject> somethings = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<SomethingObject2> somethings2 = new ArrayList();

    //Unable to pass ArrayLists of the objects that implement the interface
    PassTo(somethings);
    PassTo(somethings2);
}
```

Comment: If you read the answers in the duplicate carefully, they explain that you can use wildcards to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes the keyword was 'extends' which obviously would work for Super classes but the keyword for interfaces is 'implements' so I was confused and unsure if people had read my question properly if the fix was so simple.
I have now put in ArrayList<? extends SomethingInterface> and it works. 
Very simple fix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your `PassTo` method receive `ArrayList<SomethingInterface>` as argument.

You need to specify *somethings* and *somethings2* to accept `SomethingInterface` but you will still be able to add object `SomethingObject` and `SomethingObject2` in it.

```
ArrayList<SomethingInterface> somethings = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<SomethingInterface> somethings2 = new ArrayList();

somethings.add(something);
somethings2.add(something2);

PassTo(somethings);
PassTo(something2);
```

Comment: Yes that would work for this example however assuming I already have ArrayList<SomethingObject>. Now any functions that accept ArrayList<SomethingObject> cannot accept ArrayList<SomethingInterface>

Comment: I don't see why you would have a function that accept SomethingObject in parameter, but not SomethingObject2 as they are both child of SomethingInterface. If a comportment is specific to one, then it should be in the SomethingObject class.

Comment: This is very a simple example illustrating my problem. In my actual code I have a problem where the parent needs to deal with a list of the two objects separately as they are both different however share the same interface. I'm hoping for a way to be able to pass between an ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<Interface> or be told it's not possible. Trust me in other words. A function that is applied to a list of one object is not applicable to the other. However a function applied to a list of the interface of both objects is applicable for both.

Comment: It is not possible without using wildcard, it is illogical. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: In the case of pointing a child list to a list of type parent, the child list has restrictions the parent does not thusly problems.
However in the case of passing a child list to a function that deals with a parent list, the function can only use methods of the parent thusly all children will work with that function. 
I understand that java works by pointing between functions, just as a function such as this would work I thought java would accommodate for the parents hierarchy to take over. 
Anyway I will check out wildcards, thank you.