# Why do we use extends rather than implements with type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

Why, when defining type parameters for generic classes, do we use the keyword `extends` rather than `implements`?

eg.

```
public class C<T extends U> {}
```

where `U` is an interface?

Shouldn't it be as follows?

```
public class C<T implements U> {}
```

Comment: because implements is for interfaces, not classes.

Comment: @Stultuske But `U` is an interface, not a class.

Comment: And what is T ? If T there is considered and interface, it fits the bill.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t