# Why is it <T extends Comparable> and not <T implements Comparable>?

Tags: java, generics

Defining a class like

```
public class MyRandomList<T extends Comparable>{
    List<T> randomList;
}
```

means we can create a MyRandomList instance with any class that **implements** Comparable.

```
MyRandomList<ComparableStudent> l = new MyRandomList<ComparableStudent>();
```

Where

```
public class ComparableStudent implements Comparable<ComparableStudent>{

}
```

Should't the syntax have been `<T implements Comparable>` ?

Or am I understanding something fundamentally wrong about Java?

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: @ArnabBhagabati your question is nice, but it's already been asked. I was preparing my answer for you, but the question was closed (and I fully agree with @Ole). I posted it in another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56304595/4922375), I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put: Java does not make a distinction between interfaces and classes when defining bounds for generic type parameters. `extends` is used for both interface and class types which makes expressing [the bound direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) (link added from Sambits comment on the main post) more streamlined.