# Represent a class which is a implementation of an interface in generics java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Consider the following classes and interfaces in java.

**A**

```
public interface A{

}
```

**B**

```
public class B implements A{

}
```

**C**

```
public class C implements A{

}
```

**Some Client**

```
main(){
     //variable to refer to only a class which implements A interface
     Class<? implements A> clazz;// this is giving compile errors
}
```

**Question**

`Class<? implements A> clazz;` is giving compile errors. how do i represent a variable to hold a class which implements an interface A.

PS: i know about `<? extends A>` and `<? super A>`. But need an analogous one for interface.

Comment: Quick google search and a good answer was given here explaining there shouldn't be a difference between using the extends keyword in this case instead. [Java generics - why is "extends T" allowed but not "implements T"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t)

Comment: It's `extends`. No difference for interface Vs class.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<B> to Class<? extends A>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your intention is here but I believe you can just declare clazz as an instance of the interface.

```
main(){

 A clazz;
}
```

Then since B implements A you should be able to do something like the following with no problems

```
A = new B();
```

Comment: I want the class not the object..