# Why does Typescript use the word "extends" for generics instead of "implements"?

Tags: typescript

Why does Typescript use the word “extends” for generics that implement a certain interface? Seems it should be "implements" since the type is being referenced, not expanded.

```
interface Foo {
    print(): void 
}

Collection<T extends Foo>
```

Here “T” implements, not extends the interface. Are their any language spec/design documents/discussions about how this came to be decided?

Comment: Don't think you can find any docs, but Java for example has  the same keywords and also uses `extends` for generics. So the reason might be as simple as prior art.

Comment: `Here “T” implements, not extends the interface.` What if I use another interface as T?

Comment: This may help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints

Comment: I'm tempted to say this question is a duplicate of [Java generics - why is “extends T” allowed but not “implements T”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976441/java-generics-why-is-extends-t-allowed-but-not-implements-t)  Of course that question is about Java, not TypeScript, but it is very related (and also suffers from a lack of "canonical" answer).  I wonder if anyone has any non-opinion non-guess answer to this question.